# Absolute positioning in OpenGL with C

Tags: c, opengl, camera

(Using OpenGL, GLUT, GLU, and C)
I am trying to create a 3D game in C, and I have the camera movement, collision detection and all of the main stuff ready, however I have failed at the first hurdle. To create my rectangles I am using

```
glutSolidCube (2.0);
```

And I know about tranformations and scale and rotations, however I am looking for how to place it in a precise location. Say I had a 3D space, with XYZ. Say I had the camera at 5,5,20, looking towards 0,0,0 (So at an angle) and wanted to place a Cube at 5,2,10, and then another at -5,-2,20. How would I use these absolute positions? Also, how would I use absolute sizes, so say I wanted the one at -5,-2,20 to be 20,5,10 in size. How would I do this in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the functions:

```
glTranslatef()
glRotatef()
glScalef()
```

Additionally, also learn these:

```
glPushMatrix()
glPopMatrix()
```

Read the [OpenGL reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) for details.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks. I was just using glTranslatef which may be why it did not work, by Translate3f looks right. Thanks!

Comment: There are neither glTranslate3f nor glRotate3f.

Comment: Oops, my mistake... maybe I got confused with `glColor3f()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First forget about glutSolidCube. GLUT is not a part of OpenGL, it's just a small convenience library for it.

You must understand the OpenGL only deals with points, lines and tranangles. And it doesn't maintain a scene, but its merely drawing points, lines and triangles. Each on its own without any connotation of topology. Also OpenGL should not be confused for some math library. The functions glTranslate, glRotate, glScale and so on are a pure legacy and have been removed from contemporary OpenGL versions.

That being said...

> Say I had the camera at 5,5,20, looking towards 0,0,0 (So at an angle) and wanted to place a Cube at 5,2,10, and then another at -5,-2,20. How would I use these absolute positions? Also, how would I use absolute sizes, so say I wanted the one at -5,-2,20 to be 20,5,10 in size. How would I do this in OpenGL?

I'll go along with what you already know (which mans old OpenGL-1.1 and GLUT):

```
void draw()
{
    /* Viewport and projection really should be set in the
       drawing handler. They don't belong into the reshape. */
    glViewport(...);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    your_projection();


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(5, 5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(5, 2, 10);
    draw_cube();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-5, -2, 20);
    draw_cube();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-5, -2, 20);
    glScalef(20, 5, 10);
    draw_cube();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```